# Confusion in beginner's analysis on manifolds / differential geomtry course

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, lie-derivative

I'm following an analysis on manifolds course and there are some concepts that I find not clear at all. Let $f, g:M \to M$ be smooth, $p \in M$ and $X$ be a vector field on $M$:

1. (Solved in comments) Given a curve $\gamma$ on $M$ such that $ \gamma(0)=p, \gamma'(0)=\textbf{v}$ define the directional derivative of $f$ along $\textbf{v}$ at $p$ as $D_\textbf{v}f (p) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{1}{h}(f(\gamma(h))-f(p))$, which is itself apoint on $M$. What does that subtraction mean since $f$ outputs points on $M$? Is the directional derivative only defined for functions that output ub the tangent space? Is there a push-forward missing in the definition?
2. (Solved in comments) My professor wrote $X(fg)(p)=g\cdot X(f) + f \cdot X(g)$. What does that multiplication mean since $f$ and $g$ output points on $M$?
3. We said that $X(f)(p) := D_{X(p)} f(p)$. Is it just me or this notation is terrible? Because $X$ is also defined as a thing that eats a point $p$ on $M$ and spits a vector in $T_pM$, so one would naturally indicate $X \circ f $ as $X(f)$, but when we apply this to a point we mean a completely different thing, namely $X(f(p))$ (a vector in $T_{f(p)}M$) vs $D_{X(p)}f(p)$ (a point in $M$). Am I missing something here?
4. When we wanted to represent the Lie derivative in coordinates we started by (and I quote) observing that $$f_* \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(x) = \sum_l \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}(f(x))$$ where $f_*$ is the push-forward of $f$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ are the basis vectors given by some parametrization $\phi$. I've got no idea what this means, why would $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ take in any arguments if it is simply defined as $T\phi(e_j)$? $f_*$ is a function $:TM \to TM$, so $f_*\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ should already be defined, what does that $x$ mean? Could it be that he wanted to indicate that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ was a basis vector at the point $x$? I thought the standard notation for this was $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right|_{x}$
5. This is just a confirmation, we define the Lie derivative of a vector field $Y$ along $X$ as $$ \mathcal{L}_XY (p)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{Y(p) - (TF_X^h)(Y(F_X^{-h}(p)))}{h}$$ where $F_X^h:M \to M$ is the flow of $X$. If I understand this correctly then the term $(TF_X^h)(Y(F_X^{-h}(p)))$ is to be interpreted as moving slightly away from $p$ (the inner $F_X^{-h}(p)$ bit), applying $Y$ to it, obtaining a vector in $T_{F_X^{-h}(p)}M$ and then translating the resulting vector back in $T_pM$ via $TF_X^{h}$ so that we can confront this with $Y(p)$. Is this the purpose of that $TF_X^h$ bit? So that $Y(p)$ and the other vector live in the same space and we can perform the subtraction?
6. When defining the Lie Bracket we come across the composition of vector fields; what does that even mean? I can understand this when we define it on functions as $X(Y(f))(p) = D_{X(p)}D_{Y(p)}f(p) = \mathcal{L}_X(D_{Y(p)}f)(p)$ but on points it just doesn't make any sense since $Y(p)$ is a tangent vector and $X$ takes points in input.

Sorry for the long post but I feel like I have a lot of confusion in my head and I can't find many resources that follow the same path as my profressor; normally I'd ask my colleagues but due to covid my university is currently closed. I'll probably add more questions in the future.

Bonus: I get that these concepts are the natural generalizations of those found in $\mathbb{R}^d$, but I can't really see them in an intuitive way. Like, how can I visualize a map from a manifold to another one? And its derivative? We proved that $\mathcal{L}_XY = 0 \iff (F_X^h)_*Y = Y$ which I feel should give me a grasp of what this means, but it's currently beyond me.

Comment: For your questions 1,2, and 3, are you sure $f$ and $g$ are not functions $M \to \Bbb{R}$? Usually the notations and definitions you are using are for scalar-valued functions.

Comment: @Nick could be, but then how would I define a directional derivative and in general? Also I'm quite convinced that $X(f)$ was used in general (not 100% sure though)

Comment: Are you using a specific textbook, so that we can check the definitions you are using?

Comment: I'm following my teacher's notes, but they are in italian. For 1) it just says "let $f$ be a regular function defined in a neighbourhood of p", and for 2) it considers any $f$ and defines $X(f)(p)=Tf(X(p))$

Comment: To your concerns about notation, you're right. I have never seen good notation for smooth manifolds.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that Nick's explanation is the only one that makes sense since the only alternative would be to consider arithmetic operations in charts which sounds like not a very good idea, so I'll assume that's the problem there. 1 and 2 are solved.